# Smooth edges are sharp after rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm a complete beginner at blender so please help in a way a beginner can understand. I'm following the blender guru's blender beginner tutorial on youtube and im on the final 9th episode. I've made a donut and before I put it through a final render, the frosting is nice and smooth. But after I render it, the drips of frosting are sharp and triangular. I have NO CLUE what I did or how to fix it. It makes zero sense and I could really use some help. Heres before final rendering and after final rendering.

[image: before rendering]

[image: after rendering]

Comment: Assuming you have a subsurf modifier, check to make sure the render levels are the same as the view levels.

Comment: @Brenticus use that as the official answer so sylleth can give you credit :)

Comment: @Byron Well your answer was better than the one I would've given... So I'll let you get the credit this time :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your render settings for your subsurf modifier are at least the same or higher than your `view` settings. In the following image you can see `view` subdiv is lower than `render`.

[image]

Set your render subdivs higher or equal to your subdivs.

[image]